# Updating SDK Package

Tags: android

When starting Eclipse I get the message stating I need to update my SDK Tools.

I open the SDK Manager as requested.

I check any and/or all checkboxes.

I have only the option to delete packages. Install is greyed out.

I therefore assume I need to delete first, but I get the ominous message [i]This cannot be undone[/i].  This tells me that once deleted, I won't have the option to install the new Tools.

So how do I update my SDK Tools when the official instructions won't let me?

Comment: are u using latest eclipse?.. or which eclipse you are using?

Comment: Hell, I don't know.  About says **BuildID**, ADT Installation Details claims 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 for DDMS -- 22.3.0 for ADT pkg -- 22.6.3 ADT feature -- rest are 22.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You should create a backup of your android-sdks folder before attempting to remove it (just to be on the safe side). Then perhaps yes try to delete as you suggested. You could also manually update by simply downloading the update manually and copying that update to the android-sdks folder.

Updates provided here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Comment: My biggest question is why can't I update it in the **approved** way? Why do I have to go through all these other techniques that the 'official' instructions say I should not do?

Comment: Unfortunately that's Eclipse for you, one day it will work perfect, next all hell breaks loose. Sorry I can't provide a definitive answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Eclipse menu - Help | Check for Updates, not Window | Android SDK Manager